# When creating a function in my smart contract, how can I know what amount to specify for testing?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I wrote a small smart contract to practice (find it below). It fails for some reason when I try to test it and I wanted to know whether it was related to the _amount value as I don't know which currency it takes nor how it works.
Here is my Account struct:

```
struct Account {
    uint balance;
    uint lockedAmount;
  }
```

and here is my function (wallettobalance is just the mapping of the wallet to the struct):

```
function LockMoney(uint _amount) public canLockAmount(_amount) returns(uint result) {
    accounts[WalletToBalance[msg.sender]].balance -= _amount;
    accounts[WalletToBalance[msg.sender]].lockedAmount += _amount;
    result = accounts[WalletToBalance[msg.sender]].lockedAmount;
    return result;
  }
```

I get this error: `const error: any = new Error(message); Error: underflow` and the status of my transaction is Fail. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Javascript VM in the Remix IDE, you can specify amount for transaction at the `value` section on the left. Without explicitly stating or having code for it, solidity uses base currency, which in Ethereum is ETH.

You can specify how much ETH you want as value by amended the field there before interacting with the function. ETH also has 18 decimal places and the smallest denominator of ETH is Wei. 1ETH = 1e18WEI. You can play around with this website.
https://eth-converter.com/

Comment: Are you affiliated with eth-converter.com?